# How to find the spectral radius of a compact operator $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, spectral-radius

How to find the spectral radius of a compact operator $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ given by
$Tf(x)= \int_{0}^{1-x} f(y)\,dy$
I proved yet that $||T||\leq 1$ and the eigen values are $\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}$.

hence my operator is compact i know that $\sigma(T)\subset [-1,1]$

The other side, i know that spectral radius is given by  $r(T)=\max \{{|\lambda}|,\lambda\in\sigma(T)\}$ or equal to $\lim ||T^n||^{\frac{1}{n}}$ but i don't see how is the face of $T^n$, and for me $\max \{ \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}\}$ is $\frac{2\pi}{5}$ because $n\in\mathbb N$  right? but should be $0$ because $n\in \mathbb Z$ so $\min \frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi $ goes to $-\infty$ right?

Perhaps somebody can help me please, or give me a hint.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Non-zero points in the spectrum of  a compact operator are all eigen values. Suppose $Tf=\lambda f$ and $\lambda \neq 0$. Then $\int_0^{1-x} f(y)dy =\lambda f$. Use induction to show that $f$ is a smooth function. Differentiate to get $-f(1-x)=\lambda f'(x)$ and differentiate again to get $f'(1-x)=\lambda f''(x)$. This gives  $\lambda f'(1-x)=\lambda^{2} f''(x)$. Hence, $\lambda^{2} f''(x)=-f(x)$. Solve this to get all eigen values and eigen vectors.

Comment: I did yet in my post, but how to calculate the espectral radius @geetha290krm ? Thank you

Comment: @weymarandres Using $r(T)=\max \{{|\lambda}|,\lambda\in\sigma(T)\}$. Note that $\sigma (T)$ consists of just eigen values and possibly $0$.

Comment: Dear @geetha290krm my eigen values are $\lambda_k=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}$ só i am confused because $k\in\mathbb Z$ then $\inf \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi $ goes to $-\infty$ therefore $\sup \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}$ is $0$. I thought well?

Comment: Sorry, $\frac{1}{|\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi|}=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}$ with $k$ positive then $\max \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi}$ right? Thank you @geetha290krm

Comment: @weymarandres $k$ can be positive or negative but I think are forgetting to  maximize $|\lambda|$ instead of $\lambda$ itself.

Comment: @ geetha290krm thank you, then the $\max$ i believe is $0$ because $k\in\mathbb Z$ right?

Comment: i mean, $|\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi|\rightarrow -\infty$ with $k\rightarrow -\infty$ therefore $\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}\rightarrow 0$,  i thought in right way? Thank you @geetha290krm